# Bash shell: extract substring print at the end of the line

Tags: bash, awk, substring

I have a file with tab separated fields (6 of them). One of these fields is a string (field 3). I need to extract a substring and write it at the end of each string after a tab (at position 11). How do I do that? Separator is a symbol /, there are always 3 of them, and I need to extract what is after the second one and before the third one (ex. http://www.host.com/).

```
2       65      gf/jyhfkhjf/fg  0.5     657     hs
6745    6       lug/hgf/hgd     87      56      kg
```

The output I want:

```
2       65      gf/jyhfkhjf/fg  0.5     657     hs      jyhfkhjf
6745    6       lug/hgf/hgd     87      56      kg      hgf
```

I tried awk for a part of my work, assuming I only have a single field with a string.

```
awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {split($3,t,"/"); print $0, t[2]}' file
2       65      gf/jyhfkhjf/fg  0.5     657     hs      jyhfkhjf
6745    6       lug/hgf/hgd     87      56      kg      hgf
```